# Rails rspec controller test vs integration test

Tags: functional-testing, rspec-rails

I just completed writing a detailed rspec capybara integration and unit tests for Rails app, which includes mocking Omniauth (twitter) login, filling in forms, data validations, etc. However, I am wondering whether there is a need to write a separate controller or functional test.

Would appreciate your input and any links to further readings etc.

Answer (score 12):

I'll play devil's advocate here, since I know I'm probably in the minority with this opinion:  I actually prefer to do exceedingly thorough controller testing.  A few reasons:

1)  I find it easier to systematically test every path and outcome at the controller level than at the integration test level.  My integration tests are primarily just happy-paths, and some of the more common error paths.

2)  A lot of potential security issues occur at the controller level.  Thorough testing helps me ensure that nothing malicious can get through to my model logic.

3)  This is subjective, but it really forces me to think about some of the long-tail paths that my application might go through.  What if someone tries to for an invalid password reset token into the URL?  Controller testing ensures that I consider all options.

4)  Unlike integration tests, they're fairly straight-forward to test.  Each action is just a ruby method!

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I think if your request (integration) spec is exercising all code paths you're covered. Ryan Bates has a great Railscast about how he tests here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test?autoplay=true and about 5:05 in he says a similar thing. Like you I like to write integration tests rather than controller specs. Most of the time controllers simply front CRUD type operations anyway (especially if you're careful about keeping domain logic out of the controller), so all you're testing is the scaffolding.